# Spark dataframe decimal precision

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have one dataframe:

```scala
val groupby = df.groupBy($"column1",$"Date")    
    .agg(sum("amount").as("amount"))
    .orderBy($"column1",desc("cob_date"))
```

When applyin the window function for adding new column difference:

```scala
val windowspec= Window.partitionBy("column1").orderBy(desc("DATE"))

groupby.withColumn("diffrence" ,lead($"amount", 1,0).over(windowspec)).show()


+--------+------------+-----------+--------------------------+
| Column | Date       | Amount    | Difference               |
+--------+------------+-----------+--------------------------+
| A      | 3/31/2017  | 12345.45  | 3456.540000000000000000  |
+--------+------------+-----------+--------------------------+
| A      | 2/28/2017  | 3456.54   | 34289.430000000000000000 |
+--------+------------+-----------+--------------------------+
| A      | 1/31/2017  | 34289.43  | 45673.987000000000000000 |
+--------+------------+-----------+--------------------------+
| A      | 12/31/2016 | 45673.987 | 0.00E+00                 |
+--------+------------+-----------+--------------------------+
```

I'm getting decimal as with trailing zeros .When I did `printSchema()` for the above dataframe getting the datatype for difference: `decimal(38,18)`.Can some one tell me how to change the datatype to `decimal(38,2)` or remove the trailing zeros

Comment: please look at https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#format_number(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,%20int)

Answer (score 3):

You can cast the data with the specific decimal size like below,

```
lead($"amount", 1,0).over(windowspec).cast(DataTypes.createDecimalType(32,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure SQL, you can use the well known technique:

```
SELECT ceil(100 * column_name_double)/100 AS cost ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import DecimalType
df=df.withColumn(column_name, df[column_name].cast(DecimalType(10,2)))
```